# JQUERY_MENU On Hover

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, html-lists

I have a problem in this menu. As you can see the sub-menu vanishes before you can put your mouse over it. Could someone could help me solve this problem? (note the css is not a problem, because this version and test)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#nav ul.child").removeClass("child");

    $("#nav li").has("ul").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("current").children("ul").fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("current").children("ul").hide();
        return false;
    });     
});
```

[Here is my fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/nsrau/sH7c9/).

Comment: I think issue is in css, add margin:0 to this #nav li ul

Comment: the problem was that it had margin: 0, and margin-top: 1px; ..... I canceled margin-top and now works ... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more CSS than jQuery.    Give this a try for your CSS

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3FFtS/)

```
 /*---- CROSS BROWSER DROPDOWN MENU ----*/
  ul#nav {
     top: 10px;
     margin: 0;
     position: relative;
     background-color: #B41515;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-decoration: none;
     bottom: 30px;
     right: 3px;
     padding-left: 1px;
     padding-right: 1px;
     padding-bottom: 1px;
     padding-top: 1px;
     z-index: 1;
 }
 ul.drop a {
     display:block;
     color: #fff;
     font-family: Verdana;
     font-size: 14px;
     text-decoration: none;
}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     background: #B41515;
     color: #ffffff;
 }
 ul.drop {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 597;
     float: left;
 }
 ul.drop li {
     float: left;
     line-height: 1.3em;
     vertical-align: middle;
     zoom: 1;
     padding-left: 5px;
     padding-right: 5px;
}
 ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 599;
     cursor: default;
     background: #1e7c9a;
 }
 ul.drop ul {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 195px;
    background: #555;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
 ul.drop ul li {
     float: none; 
 } 
ul.drop ul ul {
   top: -2px;
   left: 100%;
 }
 ul.drop li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible
 }
```

Comment: the problem was that it had margin: 0, and margin-top: 1px; ..... I canceled margin-top and now works ... thanks for the help